# Knative logging: log stash - Kibana unable to fetch mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, ibm-cloud, kibana, knative-serving, knative

For Knative logging, following the instructions here - https://github.com/knative/docs/blob/master/serving/installing-logging-metrics-traces.md#elasticsearch-kibana-prometheus--grafana-setup, I tried to visualise the logs using Kibana UI (the visualization tool for Elasticsearch) but struck with the following error while configuring an index pattern — **“ Unable to fetch mapping. Do you have indices matching the pattern?” logstash**
[image]

Is there any workaround or fix for this?

**Update:** Here's what I see when I make a cURL GET request as suggested in the comment[image]

Comment: Can you show what you get when running `GET _cat/indices?v` in Dev Tools?

Comment: @Val Please find the update above

Comment: You don't seem to have any indices that match the `logstash-*` pattern

Comment: Not sure what I am missing here. I followed all the instructions and see everything working as expected except for Kibana to check the logs.

Comment: Also the response from the `_cat/indices` command is weird. Is that really the names of your indices?

Comment: yep, I ran the command and this is what I see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some additional steps which I have to perform to make this completely work. Posting here so that this may help someone facing the same issue and looking for an answer

Here are the steps,
Run the below command to apply a patch to fix the fluentd-ds pods not showing issue

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gevou/knative-blueprint/master/knative-serving-release-0.2.2-patched.yaml
```

Verify that each of your nodes have the beta.kubernetes.io/fluentd-ds-ready=true label:

```
kubectl get nodes --selector beta.kubernetes.io/fluentd-ds-ready=true
```

If you receive the No Resources Found response:
Run the following command to ensure that the Fluentd DaemonSet runs on all your nodes:

```
kubectl label nodes — all beta.kubernetes.io/fluentd-ds-ready=”true”
```

Run the following command to ensure that the fluentd-ds daemonset is ready on at least one node:

```
kubectl get daemonset fluentd-ds --namespace knative-monitoring
```

[image]

Wait for a while and run this command

```
kubectl proxy
```

Navigate to the [Kibana UI](http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/knative-monitoring/services/kibana-logging/proxy/app/kibana). It might take a couple of minutes for the proxy to work.

- Within the “Configure an index pattern” page, enter logstash-* to Index pattern and select @timestamp from Time Filter field name and click on Create button.
- To create the second index, select Create Index Pattern button on top left of the page. Enter zipkin* to Index pattern and select timestamp_millis from Time Filter field name and click on Create button.
  [image]

If the issue still exists, following the suggestions in the comments above should fix the error

```
GET _cat/indices?v
```

[image]

***Added the end-to-end findings [here](https://medium.com/vmacwrites/knative-monitoring-with-grafana-zipkin-weavescope-other-plugins-30a2d8d20344)***

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in recent versions of KNative which has been documented in this issue https://github.com/knative/serving/issues/2218. 
There is already an approved but not yet merged PR about it you can see here https://github.com/knative/serving/pull/2560.

In short, the problem is that `fluentd` pods use `system-node-critical` priority class which is no longer supported outside of `kube-system` namespace.

As a result `fluentd` pods do not get created and therefore  do not send any logs to Elasticsearch and consequently no `logstash` indexes show-up in Kibana.

As a work around for KNative v0.2.2, you can download and delete line `1909` from the release file here: 
https://github.com/knative/serving/releases/download/v0.2.2/release.yaml.

You can then install the patched version: 
`kubectl apply -f release.yaml`

If you don't want to download and edit you can get an already [patched version of release 0.2.2 here](https://github.com/gevou/knative-blueprint/blob/master/knative-serving-release-0.2.2-patched.yaml) which you can install with:

`kubectl apply -f https://github.com/gevou/knative-blueprint/blob/master/knative-serving-release-0.2.2-patched.yaml`

You can do something similar for previous versions of course.

Comment: Followed all the suggestions. But still seeing the error.

Comment: I rechecked the configuration above by installing it on a brand new GCP cluster and I can confirm that Kibana works. But I know that doesn't help. A couple of thoughts: a) Have you checked your `fluentd` pods for errors? You may also want to check the events either via `kubectl describe pod [your-fluentd-pod] -n knative-monitoring` or via GCP console `workloads => fluentd-ds => Events`. b) My cluster has 2 `n1-standard-2` nodes up when everything is installed. I noticed that small clusters run-out of memory or processing even without any apps running causing knative pods to fail to init.

Comment: Also fyi, what @val meant in the earlier comment to your question was to go to Kibana's `Dev Tools` menu and run `GET _cat/indices?v` there.

Comment: Your answers definitely helped me to find a workaround for this issue and I heartfully thank you for that. I am posting this along with my findings as an answer